# What is "WEBSERVICE_MODULE" at 1C Bitrix

Tags: .net, web-services, soap, content-management-system, bitrix

Good day!

I try to connect .Net client app and 1C Bitrix (CMS) via SOAP.

So, when i create web-service on CMS , it depends WEBSERVICE_MODULE.

What it can be? On docs:Specifies the module that will be connected by a call service.

Example:

```
<?$APPLICATION->IncludeComponent("bitrix:webservice.server","",Array(
    "WEBSERVICE_NAME" => "WebService EndPoint: Bitrix",
    "WEBSERVICE_MODULE" => "",
    "WEBSERVICE_CLASS" => "CGenericWSStub"
),
);?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

maybe this still would be helpful:

1C-Bitrix has different editions where different modules are included.

Webservice module is included only in "Эксперт" and "Бизнес" editions.
http://www.1c-bitrix.ru/products/cms/editions/#tab-table-link
[image: different editions]

**How you can know your edition of 1C-Bitrix:**

open http://**yoursiteurl**/bitrix/admin/sysupdate.php
find this words on the bottom of the page 'Редакция продукта:' and just opposite you will see your edition. Example below shows "Старт" edition
[image: example: 'Старт' edition]